# rails4 bootstrap3 ajax modal don't works

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use Boostrap 2 , modals works well. But I changed my template, this template use bootstrap 3 and modal not working. Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

in _form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'place' %>
<%= render 'modal' %>
```

in _place.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(getlatlng_path,remote: true) do  %> 
    <%= text_field_tag :search_place %>
    <%= submit_tag "search", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

in _modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p id="modal1">body…</p>
      <p id="modal2"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary", id="map-select", style="display: none", onclick="getValue()">Select</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in reports_controller.rb

```
def latlng
  ~~~
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @report}
    format.js
  end
end
```

in latlng.js.erb

```
~~~
$(".modal-body").html(content);
$(".modal-title").html('<%= $query %> search result');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

before

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

all is works well, modal-body and modal-title is changed correct, but modal doesn't appeal.
Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

in application.js

```
//= require bootstrap/jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap.min
//= require bootstrap/jquery.prettyPhoto
//= require bootstrap/jquery.isotope.min
//= require bootstrap/main
//= require bootstrap/wow.min
//= require bootstrap/jquery-1.10.2.min
//= require profile
//= require turbolinks
```

in application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap/bootstrap.min
*= require bootstrap/font-awesome.min
*= require bootstrap/animate.min
*= require bootstrap/prettyPhoto
*= require bootstrap/main
*= require bootstrap/responsive
```

in console

```
Started POST "/getlatlng" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-15 00:33:17 +0900
Processing by ReportsController#latlng as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_place"=>"kisti", "commit"=>"serach"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered reports/latlng.js.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

please help me~

Comment: What does the JS console say? Have you remembered to require bootstrap/modal in your application.js?

Comment: @MartinPoulsen I try but, also it's not work... my question